# How do i keep my class variable exclusive for every user?

Tags: python, class, variables, telegram-bot, aiogram

I'm trying to write a telegram bot, that selects a group of photos in 3 steps, using Inline Keyboards. During each of steps I call an Inline Keyboard with 2 buttons. First button selects a criteria, changes variable "selected_criteria" and calls next Inline Keyboard, 2nd button sends photos based on the variable "selected_criteria".

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
import os

button1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Criteria1", callback_data="Never")
button2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Criteria2", callback_data="Gonna")
button3 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Criteria3", callback_data="Give")
button4 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Selected Criteria", callback_data="You")
keyboard_inline = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(button1, button4)
keyboard_inline2 = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(button2, button4)
keyboard_inline3 = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(button3, button4)
keyboard_inline4 = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(button4)


class Handler:
    def __init__(self, dp: Dispatcher, chat_id):
        self.selected_criteria = ""
        self.chat_id = chat_id
        self.source_dir = ""
        dp.callback_query_handler(
            text=["Never", "Gonna", "Give", "You"]
        )(self.criteria_selection)

    async def criteria_selection(self, call: types.CallbackQuery):
        if call.data == "Never":
            self.selected_criteria = "1"
            await call.message.reply("Choose 2nd Criteria", reply_markup=keyboard_inline2)
        if call.data == "Gonna":
            self.selected_criteria = self.selected_criteria + "2"
            await call.message.reply("Choose 3rd Criteria", reply_markup=keyboard_inline3)
        if call.data == "Give":
            self.selected_criteria = self.selected_criteria + "3"
            await call.message.reply("End Selection", reply_markup=keyboard_inline4)
        if call.data == "You":
            await call.message.reply(self.selected_criteria)
            with os.scandir(self.source_dir) as entries:
                for entry in entries:
                    if entry.name.startswith(self.selected_criteria):
                        await call.message.answer_photo(photo=open(entry, "rb"))

        await call.answer()


bot = Bot(token="")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def welcome(message: types.Message):
    handler = Handler(dp, message.chat.id)
    await message.reply("Welcome chat_id= " + str(handler.chat_id), reply_markup=keyboard_inline)
    await handler.criteria_selection()


executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Variable source_dir is the folder where I keep all of the photos that I will be sending
The problem is that once there is more than 1 user of the bot, it stops working as intended, because the variable "selected_criteria" is shared between all users.

So if User1 chose all 3 criteria, but before he pushed the button to send photos, someone else chose 1st criteria, User1 is going to receive incorrect photos.

It's my first time doing a telegram bot, so i'm probably doing something wrong, if so please tell me how I can do better.